# tkinter сделать окно активным раз в секунду

Tags: python, tkinter, таймер, окно

Здравствуйте, необходимо реализовать задачу. Есть окно приложения с таймером, по нажатию кнопки "пробел" таймер начинает отсчет от 40 до 0 с интервалом в одну секунду, окно всегда находится поверх других окон. Но если перейти в другое приложение, окно станет неактивным. 
**Как сделать так, чтобы каждую секунду окно вновь становилось активным?**

```
from tkinter import *

timer_running = False
default_seconds = 40
timer_seconds = default_seconds

def timer_start_pause(event):
    global timer_running
    timer_running = not timer_running
    if timer_running:
        timer_tick()

def timer_reset():
    global timer_running, timer_seconds
    timer_running = False
    timer_seconds = default_seconds
    show_timer()

def timer_tick():
    if timer_running and timer_seconds:
        label.after(1000, timer_tick)
        global timer_seconds
        timer_seconds -= 1
        show_timer()

def show_timer():
    label['text'] = timer_seconds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    label = Label(root)
    label.pack()
    Button(root, text='reset', command=timer_reset).pack()

    root.bind('<space>', timer_start_pause)
    x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
    y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
    root.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) 

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Внутри таймера необходимо вызывать `focus_force()` для главного окна. На примере исходной функции:

```
def timer_tick():
    root.focus_force()
    global timer_seconds
    if timer_running and timer_seconds:
        label.after(1000, timer_tick)
        timer_seconds -= 1
        show_timer()
```

[Make Tkinter widget take focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842220/make-tkinter-widget-take-focus)

Тестировалось на Python 3.6, Windows 7.

**Update**
Полный код без глобальных переменных:

```
from tkinter import *

class TimerWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self, default_seconds=40):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer_running = False
        self.default_seconds = default_seconds
        self.timer_seconds = default_seconds

        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.pack()
        self.button = Button(self, text='reset', command=self.timer_reset)
        self.button.pack()

        self.bind('<space>', self.timer_start_pause)
        x = (self.winfo_screenwidth() - self.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
        y = (self.winfo_screenheight() - self.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
        self.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.wm_attributes("-topmost", True) 

    def timer_start_pause(self, event):
        self.timer_running = not self.timer_running
        if self.timer_running:
            self.timer_tick()

    def timer_reset(self):
        self.timer_running = False
        self.timer_seconds = self.default_seconds
        self.show_timer()

    def timer_tick(self):
        self.focus_force()
        if self.timer_running and self.timer_seconds:
            self.after(1000, self.timer_tick)
            self.timer_seconds -= 1
            self.show_timer()

    def show_timer(self):
        self.label['text'] = self.timer_seconds


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = TimerWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Автору стоит порекомендовать глобальную переменную, передав `timer_seconds` в качестве аргумента где необходимо.

Comment: пропустил слово *убрать*: убрать следует глобальную переменную.

Comment: В исходном примере использовал всё в рамках оригинального кода. Добавил новый код без глобальных переменных. Может также будет полезен.

Comment: я понимаю что вы код из вопроса взяли, поэтому я и пытался написать: _"автору [вопроса] стоит [посоветовать в вашем ответе ] **убрать** глобальную переменную..."_ 2- Код в ответе после обновления просто просится в свой класс отдельный.

Comment: Немного тупанул, спасибо за комментарий :)

Comment: @jfs, соглашусь и изменю код :)

Answer (score 0):

Используй функцию `название вашего окна.focus()`

вот пример:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def d1():
    ds=Toplevel(root)
    ds.focus()
def d():
    ds=Toplevel(root)
b1=Button(root, text="not focus", command=d)
b1.pack()
b=Button(root, text="focus", command=d1)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: У вас код создаёт новые окна по нажатию на кнопки (автор хочет существующее окно активным сделать).

Comment: Ето пример для функции focus.